# Power Pivot bad performance (5 hours waiting for 50M rows)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

I have to do analysis on ~50M rows and it seems that PowerPivot can't handle it. I do some ETL in PowerQuery but it seems to work properly. I takes some time to execute but I  the end data is uploaded.

However when I try to add to the data model some metrics like: average, median,  standard deviation etc., boy it stucks. I waited for 5 hours for it to be executed and in the end I had to restart computer anyway.

Additionally I've noticed that my PC behaves in unexpected way. Normally when I do something that needs higher performance (like playing games) you can feel that all resources are working hard. Computer gets warm, fans are working loudly etc. In this case it's complete silence. From time to time everything freezes for a while (like half an hour) so I can't even move mouse. Then it starts to operate for a while and whole process repeats.

I'm wondering, is it just too complex for PowerPivot/PowerQuery or maybe my computer is too slow (I have i7, 8GB ram and HDD drive in my laptop). I was also thinking about adding RAM or SSD drive but I'm not sure if it will help.

My theory was that this weird behavior of my computer is caused by some component that is a bottleneck. I was thinking that maybe my HDD is too slow and all the other resources can't operate on a full performance because reading speed is too slow. I'm not a computer scientist and I  don't know if that is possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Last week I saw PowerBI model with 6 billion records executing complex formulas in less than 5 seconds. Your 50M records is a small data set for PowerBI, Tabular or PowerPivot. Something must be wrong in your data model or your DAX, but we can't help you until you provide more specific information.

Comment: Wow,  that's impressive. Do you know if it was running on a regular computer or some kind of server? I'll describe my model in details once I'm back home. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: To a bit more specific: my model has only one table with few columns. First column is a string with two possible values, second is hour (0-24), third represents items I need to analyse so it's string (each row has different value, not very long), last one is value (integer) which I want to measure. Measures I use: sum,  average, percentile, median, standard deviation, and sum which picks top 100 items and sums value for them (combination of topn, calculate and group by functions). There are some simple pivots created out of these measures. Let me know if I should add anything else.

Comment: It was running on a regular laptop, with an i7 processor, 32 GB ram and 64 bit windows.

Comment: last measure might be worth looking at. Also, standard deviation might be expensive if your pivots have many cells (each cell calculates its own stdev). If you want to get serious, this is the best training on the topic: https://www.sqlbi.com/p/optimizing-dax-video-course/

Comment: Also, your software versions can make a big difference: Win-64, Excel 2016 64 bit work much better than previous versions, and latest PowerBi performs better than Excel/Power Pivot.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to play with these two measures and will let you know about the outcome. I have Excel 2016 Professional 64bit so it should be fine. Thanks for good advice! The course also looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

For data analysis on this scale you should consider other packages, one that comes to mind is SAS - used this to data mine 10 Meg of data into 200,000 individual files based on several criteria...

Warning SAS has a steep learning curve : very good though... There may be other packages to consider.